# Grunt tasks aren't working, grunt won't show version

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, package.json

I'm taking Udacity's Nanodegree in web design, and part of that process includes installing grunt.

I have installed node.js, npm, and the grunt CLI globally, and have installed npm and grunt on a local project. My JSON package says I have the latest version of grunt (0.4.5) and yet when I look for my version of grunt, I get the following errors:

Registering "grunt-responsive-images" local Npm module tasks.
Local Npm module "grunt-responsive-images" not found. Is it installed?

Registering "grunt-contrib-clean" local Npm module tasks.
Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-clean" not found. Is it installed?

Registering "grunt-contrib-copy" local Npm module tasks.
Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-copy" not found. Is it installed?

Registering "grunt-contrib-mkdir" local Npm module tasks.
Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-mkdir" not found. Is it installed?

This also prevents tasks from running. I've spent a few hours with a friend trying to figure this out, posting my question to the Udacity forums, as well as googling the aforementioned errors without getting nearer to my conundrum. I also edited my PATH variable to ensure that it encountered node.js.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance,
Dana

p.s. I'm using Windows 7, if that impacts the answer in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt tasks are loaded in as grunt plugins. Those plugins are installed through NPM as well. The errors your log is showing are caused by the fact those plugins aren't installed yet on your machine.

Install them with the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-responsive-images grunt-contrib-clean grunt-contrib-copy grunt-contrib-mkdir
```

Comment: Thank you. In the end I uninstalled grunt and started afresh, this time following the official instructions in a closer way, and it all went smoothly. Phew!